# assigning multiple variable in one line with the hash returning from the method in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a method that returns a hash map `{ :name => "Test", :desc => "Test Description }`. It will always return `:name` and `:description`.

How can I assign 2 variables in with the returned hash.

I could do this but it will call the method twice:

```
@name, @desc = get_name_desc_map[:name], get_name_desc_map[:desc]
```

I only want to call the method once.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Very simple using Ruby's *parallel assignment* :

```
@name, @desc = get_name_desc_map.values
```

Other way is ( If you don't know the order of keys in the original hash ) :

```
@name, @desc = get_name_desc_map.values_at(:name, :desc)
```

[`Hash#values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) and [`Hash#values`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-values) .